# IIS is not accessible remotely on VPS hosting

Tags: iis, asp.net

Hosting at Windows 10 Pro, not Server.

I'm trying to share local IIS website using external static IP provided by hoster.
When I go to a website using http://localhost it works fine, but if I'm trying to open it using IP I always see an error page saying "Can't reach a website".

1. I can ping IP from any computer.
2. I can start Apache server, and it will be visible from outside.
3. IIS bindings for this website are set to "All Unassigned" for port 80 and "All Unassigned" for port 443.
4. Firewall and antivirus are temporarily disabled
5. Folder "inetpub" gives full control permissions to Administrators, NonManaged Pool User, DefaultAppPool, Users, System, Network Service.
6. This is a .NET Core application, so it's starting on localhost:5000 and IIS simply redirects all requests to it.
7. Tried to remove all ACL rules using "netsh", then added rule to allow all users access to "http://*:80/"

**Why Apache works fine everywhere, but IIS is available only on localhost?**

Comment: If your ASP application is listening to localhost:5000 then it’s inaccessible from outside the server it’s running on

Comment: @Ramhound yes, but IIS is used as a proxy https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2016/jun/06/publishing-and-running-aspnet-core-applications-with-iis so, all requests go to port 80 and then are supposed to be redirected to port 5000

Comment: Additionally, firewall and windows defender are completely disabled, so all ports should be open. Am I wrong?

Comment: Just because your firewall is disabled doesn’t mean you have anything listening on that port.  Based on the behavior you describe you don’t have anything listening.  Your IIS is only configured to listen to localhost.Just as you defined a host in Apache you have to do the same with IIS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved :)

After discussion in the comments I realized that I need to try to share Kestrel server first that is usually started at localhost:5000 by default. At this point, IIS must be skipped for simplicity. This article describes how make Kestrel listening for an incoming request on specific port.

https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2016/sep/28/external-network-access-to-kestrel-and-iis-express-in-aspnet-core

https://www.google.com/search?q=run+kestrel+on+specific+ip

Specifically, appsettings.json should contain endpoint to call. This endpoint should be either 0.0.0.0 or specific IP to listen for.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/55806584/437393

```
"Kestrel": {
  "EndPoints": {
    "Http": {
      "Url": "http://0.0.0.0:5000"
    }
  }
}
```

Or Program.cs should call method UseUrls()

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
        var host = new WebHostBuilder()
            .UseUrls("http://0.0.0.0:5000/")
            .UseKestrel()
            .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .UseIISIntegration()
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .Build();

        host.Run();
}
```

At this point, starting Kestrel directly using command "dotnet MyProject.dll" should make website visible on static IP and port 5000, e.g. xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:5000

**Now, coming back to IIS.**

By default, Windows 10 resolves all host names to IPv6, so to make IIS listen for IPv4 this command must be executed.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14029629/iis-cant-access-page-by-ip-address-instead-of-localhost

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34212765/how-do-i-get-the-kestrel-web-server-to-listen-to-non-localhost-requests

```
netsh http add iplisten xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx    // Static IP
```